# Allow AWS OpenID Connect through Security Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, security-groups, openid-connect

I have a GitLab self-hosted instance running in AWS EC2. Its associated security group blocks all incoming external traffic except for a handful of individual IP addresses.

To automatically deploy code from GitLab to an AWS S3 bucket in a separate account, I create an *Identity Provider* in that separate account IAM console [following the exact process described in this post](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2023/03/01/how-to-deploy-react-to-amazon-s3/).

Everything works exactly as intended if I allow world access to port 443 in my EC2 instance's security group. Unfortunately, that's not an option I can take permanently. I could add the CIDR block from where AWS seems to be making the request but that doesn't seem sustainable, as the CIDR block could change at any time.

**Do you know of an approach that would allow me to continue blocking all incoming traffic except for my few hand-curated IP addresses *and* the request from AWS to authenticate GitLab using OpenID connect?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue, all I can think of is [aws managed prefix list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-aws-managed-prefix-lists.html#available-aws-managed-prefix-lists)  but it seems like I can't find any prefix list that might be suitable for this case

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix this issue is to expose only the two endpoints required for STS to verify the connection:

1. https://BASE_SERVER_URL/.well-known/openid-configuration
2. The URL you'll find in the first url under the jwks_uri field
   You can use an Application Load Balancer (ALB) in front of your EC2 instance and utilize ALB rules instead of security groups.